# JQuery: using .LIVE problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery code:

```
$("#myDIV li:eq(0)").live('click',function(){ funcA(); });
$("#myDIV li:eq(1)").live('click',function(){ funcB(); });
$("#myDIV li:eq(2)").live('click',function(){ funcC(); });
$("#myDIV li:eq(3)").live('click',function(){ funcD(); });
```

And realized it's really inefficient.

So I tried the following, which I believe is much more effect; however, the code does not work:

```
var tab_node = $("#myDIV li");
tab_node.eq(0).live('click',function(){ funcA(); });
tab_node.eq(1).live('click',function(){ funcB(); });
tab_node.eq(2).live('click',function(){ funcC(); });
tab_node.eq(3).live('click',function(){ funcD(); });
```

Any idea how I can make my code more efficient while also work?

**UPDATE:**

From the answers below, it sounds like these two statements are not equalavent.

*New Question:* Is there any way to run my original code more efficient?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis at the end of all those lines.

Comment: @Yuriy, Whoops, sloppy copy/paste. Updated now.

Comment: please explain what you want to happen.  There may be a totally different way to approach the problem that will be a lot more efficient.  However, when you all you are asking for is `run my original code`, we don't have much option to change it, since we can only guess at what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myDIV li').live('click' , function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if (index == 0) funcA();
    if (index == 1) funcB();
    if (index == 2) funcC();
    if (index == 3) funcD();
});
```

**Edit:**
Even more fun ..

```
(function () {
    var funcs = [funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD];
    $('#myDIV li').live('click' , function() {
        funcs[$(this).index()](); // should check array boundary, but.. meh
    });
}());
```

**EDIT 2**

and of course if you want observe only the first 4 LI's use this:

```
 $('#myDIV li:lt(4)')
```

Comment: This looks like it is probably what the asker wants, but the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The first code works because it's binding the event to a live selector.

The second code is applying a live to a specific element (the `.eq(x)` returns a jQuery object with a collection of just *that* element) - it's not applying it to a selector to listen to in the future.

With the way you have it set up (each `<li>` calling a different function), I can't really think of an elegant way to approach the issue.

Also, why are you using `live` for such a specific selection? Are those `<li>`'s removed/added as the page lives on?

Unless you truly need `live`, I would do it like so..

```
var tab_node = $("#myDIV li");
tab_node.eq(0).click(funcA);
tab_node.eq(1).click(funcB);
tab_node.eq(2).click(funcC);
tab_node.eq(3).click(funcD);
```

Comment: So ... is there a more efficient way to run my original code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using LIVE because I'm dynamically creating the tabs on page load

Comment: @TeddTedd - Are they only added ONCE? If so, `live` is still not the right solution. You should be applying the code above after you create those tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't really make much sense to me if you are going to be adding new `li` items on the fly.

It probably isn't going to behave how you think it will.

The first 4 things will get the event handlers you want, anything added later wont, unless it is added so that it appears in the top 4 spots in the list.   But if things *are* added at the top of the list, the original items that used to be there won't be unbound/reassigned.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li> <!-- will call funcA when clicked -->
    <li>B</li> <!-- will call funcB when clicked -->
    <li>C</li> <!-- will call funcC when clicked -->
    <li>D</li> <!-- will call funcD when clicked -->
</ul>
```

Now if you add a new `li` anywhere under that, it won't get a click handler (in which case you don't need `live`).   If you add a new one in the middle, this will happen:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li> <!-- will call funcA when clicked -->
    <li>B</li> <!-- will call funcB when clicked -->
    <li>New thing that got added</li> <!-- will call funcC when clicked -->
    <li>C</li> <!-- will call funcC when clicked -->
    <li>D</li> <!-- will call funcD when clicked -->
</ul>
```

Why don't you explain what you want to happen on the page so that we can help?

Answer (score 0):

From the caveats in the docs:

> DOM traversal methods are not fully supported for finding elements
>   to send to .live(). Rather, the
>   .live() method should always be called
>   directly after a selector, as in the
>   example above.

The example above shows:

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

You need to apply to the selector, not the DOM. Is there a particular reason you find your original code inefficient? It should be just fine. The only suggestion I'd have is to delay the filtering:

```
$("#myDIV li").live('click', function(e){
   // analyze the event target here to determine the actual element
   // to do so, use $(e.target)
});
```

By doing this, you've only got 1 live event, and the selector is simpler too. The tradeoff is handling the switch statement for each target element in your own code.